# nginx/gunicorn/flask server timed out only when using flask-mail

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn, flask-mail

I've created an app using flask on python3 and deployed it using nginx and gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04. Everything worked fine (locally and on the server) until I set up mail support using flask-mail. On the local flask development server everything worked fine, but on the Ubuntu server I always get a 502 Bad Gateway error. This is only when I try sending mails. On "normal" routes everything works fine. The mail data is 100% correct.

I'm using gunicorn as my wsgi server. It is kept alive by supervisord. I've created a test route only sending an "hello world" email. I've looked in every single log file, but there is no output. I've also tried to use the flask development server for testing purposes on port 5000 and it gave me the following error:

```
504 - Gateway Time-out
[2019-02-12 13:53:37,083] ERROR in app: Exception on /test/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/application/settings/routes.py", line 655, in change
     change_email_mail("info@fabio-oelschlaeger.de", "abc")
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/application/mail.py", line 70, in change_email_mail
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 491, in send
    with self.connect() as connection:
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 144, in __enter__
    self.host = self.configure_host()
  File "/home/ubuntu/layoutboxx/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 156, in configure_host
    host = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 1031, in __init__
    source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 1037, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Feb/2019 13:53:37] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.0" 500 -
```

My mail sending function:

```
def change_email(email):
    msg = Message(
        "Confirm email change",
        recipients=[email]
    )
    msg.body = render_template("mails/change_email.txt")
    msg.html = render_template("mails/change_email.html")
    mail.send(msg)
```

The test blueprint:

```
settings = Blueprint("settings",
    __name__,
    static_folder="static",
    template_folder="templates",
    subdomain="settings"
)

@settings.route("/test/")
def change():
    change_email("my@mail.com")
    return ""
```

I've also added the SERVER_NAME of flask ("mydomain.com"). When I call settings.mydomain.com/test/ I get that timeout error.

I really need help figuring out what's wrong with my configuration. My nginx configuration is some standard reverse proxy like found a thousand times on the internet pointing to http://localhost:8000. Gunicorn is running 3 workers.

Comment: You should try to "unstack" : calling a python script that send Message, timing it, to see how long it takes. If timing is high, the problem is perharps not a python one. Try using "mail" command to send a message, timing it. And so on ... to locate which part of the "sending email message" could lead to a timeout.

Comment: Well I cannot unstack it more than I've done it now. My current test code above is the most minimal way i can imagine. Could you be more explicit what you mean with "Try using 'mail' command"?

Comment: Your program is timing out on connecting tot your mail server. Is a mail server running? How did you configure it? That is not your Flask or nginx confiuration.

Comment: Yes the mail server is running. I did not configure it myself since it is hosted by our old webhoster (df.eu). I tried different mail servers hosted on different places. All of them work on my local machine, but they do not work on our hosted server. There's nothing wrong with the mail servers. The error posted above suggests that the smtplib used by flask-mail got a timeout.

Comment: smtplib used by flask-mail is the standard lib for SMTP in the python language. Your stack trace just show a time out, nothing wrong with smtplib or flask-mail. By "unstack", I mean, just plain python code, no more nginx, gunicorn, supervisor in front. Just call change_email for example from a "flask shell" and time it. Then, unstack once more, throwing flask-mail and using smtplib directly. Then, use something not in python, to try to reach the SMTP server (and of course time it !)

Comment: The error above is from using plain python without supervisor and gunicorn. I tried calling change_email from a "flask shell" but it says I need a running app-instance. I can reach the smtp-server by not using python. The error above shows us that it got stuck in the create_connection-function of socket.py. At this level I am not able to change anything to test the differences.
I don't get the sense of timing everything if I do not have access on the lower levels of the python packages. I know from other tests that it's a problem inside of mail.send(msg) on which I'm not able to connect.

Comment: Well I did some more tests on it: I cannot reach the smtp server from my ubuntu webserver so I'm going to ask my hosting provider if he knows what to do.

Comment: @bliepp did you ever sort this out? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @DukeSilver Yes. Sorry, I totally forgot to post my solution here. It was just that my hosting provider had the outgoing SMTP port closed. I had to ask them to open it to the public. I was able to open ports inside my cloud hosting network internally but had to ask for permission to open it to the public.